# How to leave out a row of a table in a barpot?

Tags: bar-chart

I need to eliminate the "prefer not to Answer" option on my graph as no one used that response.

I've tried subsetting the information without any luck.

coding for the current graph including that response:

```
gender <- prop.table(table(groupproject$Q2, groupproject$Q13))

gender 

barplot(t(gender), beside = T, names.arg = c("Female", "Male", "Other", "Prefer Not to Answer"), main = "Do Men's or Women's Sports \nReceive More Advertising, \nResponse by Gender", ylab= "Proportion of Respondents", ylim = c(0, .6), col = c("red", "blue", "green"))
legend("topright", legend = c("Don't Know", "Men's", "Women's"), fill = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

I'd like to have the side by side graph for 3 of the 4 gender response options.

Current Bar graph

[image: sample bar graph]